# need to display the current product attribute in product page woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently I have this code which displays an array.

```
global $product;
print_r( $product->get_attributes() );
```

it displays this

```
Array ( [pa_magnetic-or-screw-fix] => Array ( [name] => pa_magnetic-or-screw-fix [value] => [position] => 0 [is_visible] => 1 [is_variation] => 1 [is_taxonomy] => 1 ) )
```

What I really want is to display only this "pa_magnetic-or-screw-fix" and not the whole array.

and that will change if the product has different attributes

something like this? below is wrong but the idea is there

```
echo $product->get_attributes()['name'][0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't quite work like that.  You are trying to call a function (get_attributes) and simultaneously read the results of the function in the form of an array.  Try setting the result of the function to a variable and then echoing to the screen.  The code below will print the names of all attributes.  If you just want the first one, you will need to make some changes.

```
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();

foreach($attributes AS $key=>$data) {
  echo $data[name];
}
```

Comment: HI, sorry but I still cannot display it, i copied your code and its not displaying anything, sorry i am bad at this

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to use the data array as an object rather than an array.  I made a small edit.  Any difference?

And no need to apologize!  Everybody starts somewhere!

Comment: Hi @tjfo its working now, its showing what i wanted, thank you